# Finding if a string is in string in sass

Tags: sass, mixins

I want an if statement to show if a string is inside another string in sass.

How do i do this in a mixin?

```
 @mixin hello($mystring) {
 }
```

Comment: Not. Mixins are not functions, but there's [a predefined function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#string_functions): `str-slice($string, $start-at, [$end-at])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str-index`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#str_slice-instance_method) to achieve this.

**SCSS**

```
@mixin hello($mystring) {
  @if (str-index("Hello World", $mystring)) {
    background-color: green;
  }
  @else {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.test {
  @include hello("World");
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.test {
  background-color: green;
}
```